# Delphi: Migrating from BDE to DBExpress Tutorial

Tags: delphi, dbexpress, bde

I'm attempting to migrate a Delphi application using BDE, with DBF/MDX data files, to DBExpress using local data files.

Simply replacing TTable components with TClientDataset resulted in errors involving the index properties.

I Googled it and all I came up with is an article by Dr. Bob which has no mention of indexes, and does not demonstrate how to use the sort method. All the other articles were general descriptions of DBExpress with no details relevant to me.

Are there any tutorials/examples of the steps to follow?

Comment: Your specific question makes little sense. WHy are you replacing a TTable with a ClientDataSet? Detail what you're trying to accomplish? Do you think TClientDataSet is the Do Everything Component to replace TTable? Did you hope that TClientDataSet will do everything you want? Nobody can guess what you want here. Perhaps a code sample? Were you using BDE with dBase files? Please be clear.

Comment: I wrote a series of blog entries about converting a BDE application to dbExpress/Firebird. You might want to look at this entry: http://nbnewman.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-dbexpress-conclusions.html

Comment: I did a video on BDE migrations for Code Rage III some years ago http://learndelphi.tv/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=79

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, TTable and TClientDataSet are very different data access methods. I will suggest 2 migration paths:

1. As you sayd about DBF/MDX, pay attention to Advantage Database and TAdsTable. You will find it more compatible with TTable than with TClientDataSet and dbExpress.
2. Consider [Anydac](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) and its [TADTable](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/unified-api.html#LDV) as a migration path. TADTable looks as a compatible and more fast TTable replacement, additionally to other Anydac features.

Comment: This app is used by a non-profit organization.  I would rather use a free database.

Comment: You can use Anydac (commercial) with free db's - Firebird, PostgreSQL, SQLite, SQL Server Express, etc.

Answer (score 1):

TClientDataset local files unfortunately are not a replacement for the BDE as a local database engine. Basically, they are in-memory datasets with the capability to save data on disk. But they lack many features you can find in the BDE. If your needs are minimal they can work (you can define indexes inside the client dataset TIndexDefs property), but they could be not what you need.

Moreover TClientDataset is not a dbExpress related component. They were actually introduced with MIDAS (later renamed Datasnap) as the client (hence the name) counterpart of a remote dataset in a multitier application (the capability of disk storage allows for disconnected operations).

dbExpress is a data access layer that can work with different database servers through "drivers", as ODBC/BDE/OLEDB do. It was decided to have only unidirectional datasets in dbExpress, reusing the caching/cursor capabilities of the already existing TClientDataset to provide the bidirectional cursor and cache. If you're using TClientDataset only, you're not using dbExpress at all, and TClientDataset can work with any dataset implementing the required interfaces (including BDE ones).

You should look at alternatives like SQLite, Firebird (there is an "embedded" version if you need only local access) or Postgres if you're looking for small and free engines (MySQL is free only if your application is GPL), or there are several other engines available from stripped down versions of commercial ones (i.e. SQL Server Express and Oracle Express), or relatively cheap ones.

Comment: Are there any comparisons of features between these alternatives?

Comment: You can start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems, but you should really look for the one that fits your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason you can't find people doing that; it's not just a bad idea, it's probably nearly impossible.

I would like to suggest that you abandon the idea of using ClientDataSet as it is not to be thought of as "the only database you'll ever need", and consider using either IBObjects [commercial!] plus Firebird [free], or dbExpress + a supported SQL Db, or Interbase Express (IBX) components that come with Delphi.

You will find that you either need a full relational SQL dbms, even a very small or light one, to replace the BDE and even the featureset you might have been used to with dBase, Access, or Paradox tables.

In that case, then the [usual tutorials](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/a/dbexpressguide.htm) apply perfectly to your situation.